# Can we achieve encapsulation using namespace?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

Can we achieve encapsulation using namespace in c++ ? Or is it compiler dependent ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "encapsulation".

Comment: if i want to encapsulate the data !!?

Comment: Edit : I'm not sure what level of encapsulation you want to achieve with namespaces, but the behavior of namespaces is not compiler dependent. So at least the answer to that part is that it can't be compiler dependent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve a degree of encapsulation using namespaces.

The obvious limitation is that you can't create instances of namespaces, so the things you encapsulate in a namespace won't normally support instances either. So, if you want to encapsulate something like "how was the program configured to run", a namespace probably works fine. If you want to encapsulate data you're going to store about each item in a database of items, chances are that a namespace isn't going to be much (if any) help.

To truly restrict access to data, you have to use namespaces in conjunction with other features. In particular, names in an anonymous namespace are visible (without qualification) to code in the same translation unit--but are completely invisible outside that translation unit.

```
// A.cpp
namespace { 
    int foo;
}

int bar() {
    // this code has free access to foo
}

// B.cpp
int baz() { 
    // this code has no access to foo
}
```

So in this case, we've encapsulated access to `foo`, so only the code in `A.cpp` can access it. Much like with a member of a class, code in A.cpp can also pass a reference or pointer to `foo` to some other code outside A.cpp, to give it access to `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of.  [Per wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) encapsulation is

> the bundling of data with the methods that operate on that data, or the restricting of direct access to some of an objects components.

If you are just focusing on the first part, then the answer is yes.  It allows the grouping of functions and variables into a box.

If you use the second half, then the answer is no. Everything in the namespace is visible to the outside and can be accessed.  Basically all you are doing in indirecting the access.

---

If you want encapsulation, just use a class.  They are built for it.